# Issues in css floating property in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have been created simple webpage by using html and css.

Here is the worked jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/y7xmr6ct/ [part of work only]

In header cart-summary section displayed in all browsers expect ie like this: http://s4.postimg.org/tuvx8avt9/Untitled_1.png

But in ie8, displayed left side of my header.

I tried to use `clear:left;` or `width:100%;` to my class `.large--right,` but nothing change.

Here is my css:

```
.large--right {
    float: right !important;
    }
```

and also I in my `#footer {border-top: 1px solid #ddd;}` didn't work in ie8

May i know, how can i fix this?

Can anyone help me to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I used Chrome to open your fiddle and it is not behaving as your picture shows. So it's not just a problem with IE8.

Comment: I just show you only css code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support media queries. You're code is mobile first and so because the media queries aren't firing, the layout is the mobile styles.

Take a look  at [RespondJS](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for media query support in IE8.

Comment: how can i use respond.js? @guy. and may i know about modernizr.js ? thanks

Comment: You could either download the script and link to the script locally, or use a CDN to add it such as: `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>`

Comment: Modernizr is slightly different as this detects what features are supported on the current browser and adds/removes classes with which you can style accordingly. There are more in depth features of modernizr using JS but respond would be the better solution for your problem.

Comment: but in search box ,placeholder value didn't display in ie8 @guy

Comment: The placeholder is a different issue, they are also not supported in IE8. This can be solved with [this script](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) by Mathias Bynens. See the readme for info on how to install

Comment: can you please take a look border-top to my footer please?

Comment: so finally,, we have to use multiple js and multiple css to fixing ie8 issue,, there is no only one alternative to fix this right?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I would suggest only loading them on IE8 using [conditional comments](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/). I would guess that the border issue is to do with media queries too so add those scripts and see if it works.

Comment: @selva just select his answer as the right answer and we can all go back to having a nice day. BTW the other old school option would be to add a separate style sheet for IE8 but why do that when you can use respond.js

Comment: i added respond.js file and i can't able to understand, how to install mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder
.. can you please help me?

Comment: You need to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-placeholder/2.0.8/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>` to your head. Then call it on all your inputs e.g. `<script>$('input, textarea').placeholder();</script>`. It also requires jquery, `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You will learn more by trying to figure it out than by me giving you all the answers.

Comment: sorry for disturbing.. may i know, where i can add this one <script>$('input, textarea').placeholder();</script>?

Comment: Either in a `<script>` tag before your closing `</body>` tag, or in a separate js file. [Javascript Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)